# Why does one __import__ statement affect the validity of the next one?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I was looking at some code with two `__import__` statements, and the second `__import__` statement doesn't work unless the first one has already been run.

The directory structure is like this:

```
dir1
 |-__init__.py
 |-subdir1
 |  |-__init__.py
 |  |-file1.py
 |  |-file2.py
 |
 |-subdir2
    |-__init__.py
    |-file1.py
    |-file2.py
```

The code has two `__import__` statements:

```
m = __import__('dir1.'+subdir1, fromlist=[file1])
...
m = __import__(file2, fromlist=[class_inside_file2])
```

The first one makes sense - it is roughly the equivalent of doing

```
from dir1.subdir1 import file1
```

but allows for the subdirectory and file to be provided dynamically. It is the second statement that I don't understand why it works. It looks like it should be the equivalent of

```
from file2 import class_inside_file2
```

This shouldn't work as `file2.py` is in `subdir1`, but my current working directory is two levels above that. Additionally, all of the `__init__.py` files are empty.

As you would expect, the second import statement fails with an `ImportError` if it is run by itself. However, **after the first import statement has run the second one works. Why?**

Comment: Where is the code that has the `__import__`s?  Also, does the second one have `file2` or `"file2"`?  It's not clear from your post which things are variables and which are literal strings.

Comment: @BrenBarn most of them are variables that will hold those literal values when the code is evaluated, i.e `file2` will have the value `"file2"`.

Comment: Check that the first import doesn't overwrite the value of `file2`, it shouldn't given what you've posted, but I'm guessing this isn't the actual code.

Comment: @PeterGibson: But then it's important what variables they are (e.g., if they're accessed via another module) and whether the first import does anything to them.

Comment: Like @PeterGibson, I wasn't able to replicate this. Are you able to reproduce the example you've provided us?

Comment: Does file1 modify `sys.modules` at all?

Comment: @grc No, but it does modify `sys.path`. Thanks for having me look for that!

Comment: Note that `help(__import__)` states "Because this function is meant for use by the Python
    interpreter and not for general use it is better to use
    importlib.import_module() to programmatically import a module."

Comment: @PeterGibson I agree. I didn't write this code, but I was trying to understand why in the world it was working when it seemed like it shouldn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not just the __import__ statements as I can't replicate this behavior.

```
$ mkdir -p dir1/subdir1 dir1/subdir2
$ touch dir1/__init__.py dir1/subdir1/__init__.py dir1/subdir2/__init__.py
$ echo "print '1.1'" > dir1/subdir1/file1.py
$ echo "print '1.2'" > dir1/subdir1/file2.py
$ echo "print '2.2'" > dir1/subdir2/file2.py
$ echo "print '2.1'" > dir1/subdir2/file1.py
```

Gives the following structure:

```
$ find . -name "*.py"
./dir1/__init__.py
./dir1/subdir1/__init__.py
./dir1/subdir1/file1.py
./dir1/subdir1/file2.py
./dir1/subdir2/__init__.py
./dir1/subdir2/file1.py
./dir1/subdir2/file2.py
```

However the 2nd __import__ command you've posted fails as expected:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 18 2013, 11:23:24)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 4.2 (clang-425.0.24)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> subdir1 = 'subdir1'
>>> file1 = 'file1'
>>> m = __import__('dir1.'+subdir1, fromlist=[file1])
1.1
>>> file2 = 'file2'
>>> class_inside_file2 = '*'
>>> m = __import__(file2, fromlist=[class_inside_file2])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named file2
```

Comment: Was just going to post the same thing.

Comment: This is not an answer.  A comment on the question, saying just your first sentence, would be better.

Comment: @BrenBarn I considered that, but this allows others to try it as well (on different platforms for instance) and to correct my process if there are errors. Why do you feel less information would be better?

Comment: @PeterGibson: Better to lean on the asker to post (in the question) what *he* is doing and then let other people try that.

Comment: @BrenBarn would posting the code sample on a 3rd party site and linking in a comment be preferable do you think?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @WarrenDew yes sorry I understand that - however I feel that the additional information I supplied is valuable, but is too long to include in a comment. Does it damage the Question to post it as an answer?

Comment: @PeterGibson seeing as the issue was a side-effect of the first import, I'd say this is actually a very relevant answer.

Comment: I think I can see why someone might have thought this was not an answer, but I think I agree it *is* an attempt to answer. I would just perhaps suggest (for an edit here, or just for the future) to start off in a way which more clearly indicates it really is an answer.

Answer (score 5):

It turns out the explanation is rather dumb. `file1` modifies `sys.path` to add `subdir1` to the path. With `subdir1` on the path, it can obviously find `file2` directly without having specify any packages.

Moral of the story - side effects (like things happening when you import a module) are dumb because it can frequently cause issues that seem bizarre and can be hard to diagnose.